# Meaning of "if x == "#" or not x:"

Tags: python, esri

So I'm reading through some code, and I come across this statement. "x", in this case, is user input so I assume it is some form of validation, but what does it do? x == not x doesn't make any sense, and what does "#" mean?

Here is the offending chunk of code:

```
def main(*argv):
try:

    #Get FC and Fields
    inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    if inputFC =="#" or not inputFC:
        inputFC = "Tooldata\\InputFC" # provide a default value if unspecified
```

Comment: Read it as `if (x == y) or not x` rather than `if x == (y or not x)`.

Comment: Essentially if the input is a pound/hash sign or if the input is null (None in Python), then the conditional will evaluate true

Comment: as @Kevin pointed out first it tests if input is hash, if not the other side of the or tests to see if there is nothing in it. For efficiency sake those two tests should really be reversed, especially if you would have a long chain of ors. No sense in testing if inputFC is "#" if it is empty in the first place.

Comment: @rfj001, it is not just `None` it is any falsey value like an empty string, list etc..

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense now. Guess I need to review my order of operations.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh true. Forgot that empty string evaluates to False in Python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inputFC == "#" or not inputFC` is a boolean expression with two parts:

1. `inputFC == "#"` – This checks whether `inputFC` equals to the string `"#"`.
2. `not inputFC` – This checks whether `inputFC` is *not trueish* which means that it’s *not not empty* (i.e. empty).

Both conditions are combined using the `or` operator, so just one condition needs to match to make the whole expression evaluate to true.

Comment: Wouldn't `not inputFC` mean that it *is* empty?

Comment: No problem. I had to phrase it as a question just in case. Double-negatives can often be confusing when trying to explain them, especially in or/and type contexts :)